# Wordpress HTTP API with twilio

Tags: php, wordpress, api, twilio

I am trying to send sms messages using Twilio API in Wordpress, but I don't understand what is `curl -u`. Now I want to send sms using twilio and wordpress via [wp_remote_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post).

See [twilio send sms docs API (via JSON)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)

My code:

```
function sending_sms_via_twilio_api(){

$oauth_args = array(
                    "body" => array(
                                    "Body" => "Hello World",
                                    "To"   => "0000000",
                                    "From" => "5555555",
                                ),

                    "my_Sid:my_token"
                );
$response   =   wp_remote_post('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC28fcd041ffe3edb8029779894b7912d3/Messages.json', $oauth_args);
$result = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true );
print_r($result);
}
```

Result is:

> Array ( [code] => 20003 [detail] => Your AccountSid or AuthToken was
>   incorrect. [message] => Authentication Error - No credentials provided
>   [more_info] => [status] => 401 )

Any solutions?

Comment: is that your actual code? i think you need to find out what to put on `"my_Sid:my_token"`

Comment: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I have my token and my sid and i used it, but not working api!

Answer (score 1):

That is a simple authentication problem. You should check your credentials again.

A `GET` call on `https://{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts` with wrong credentials give that problem.

Also the api response give this error page as advice for you:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't under stan, what is -u in php curl?

Comment: *curl is an open source command line tool and library for transferring data with URL syntax* the -u param it's for authentication purpouse. This is the manual page... http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

Comment: Ok what is the solution?

Comment: You should check your credentials again.

Comment: I checked my credentials

Comment: If you put your credentials in this URI and put it in your browser navigation bar what happens?
[https://{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts](https://{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts)

Comment: What do you mean with nothing?